# Can modern CPUs run PhysX with high FPS?

Tags: technical-issues, performance, graphics-card, framerate, nvidia-physx

PhysX is over ten years old now, and back then running PhysX supported games with cpu-only PhysX setting guaranteed low framerates.

Can today's fastest processors like Intel i9 paired with non-nvidia GPU run those old games with cpu-only PhysX setting with good FPS?

Are there modern CPU benchmarks with old PhysX games?

Comment: I think the question here is: can contemporary CPUs on systems without dedicated GPUs run older games with PhysX enabled (and presumably smoothly)?

Answer (score 2):

If you watch [PhysX CPU vs GPU vs GPU PhysX](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A6UNsNI6yko) then you'll see that PhysX on CPU is still abysmal even just 4 years ago reducing framerate 50-90% less than just running it on the GPU itself. Most games don't even support PhysX on CPU anyways.

Maybe if you had a particularly bad GPU like the GT 1030 or something then CPU PhysX might outperform it but you'd be a fool to pair a GT 1030 with a CPU that can run PhysX better than it can.

If you're trying to achieve PhysX while using a high-end GPU like the AMD 7900 XT then then GPU will always be waiting for the CPU PhysX to catch up and you'd be throwing performance out the window.